# Jquery-router, route function is not called

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, url-routing

I am using [Jquery-router](https://github.com/thorsteinsson/jquery-routes) with a single route defined as,

```
$.routes.add('/news/', function() {
  $('#content').html("this is the news page")
});
```

When i click on a tag with href value as `#news`, the window url changes to `http://localhost:8000/#news`.

But neither the route function is getting called nor the page content gets changed.

How to use the router functionality with jquery (or) is there any other similar jquery library for client side routing?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: I think you need to read the Usage part again in the documentation. You need to bind the tag with a click handler and use $.routes.find and .routeTo to make the whole thing work.